# If condition is giving Error in Oracle Package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new to oracle database i created a PL/SQL package with some if else statements. It contains three procedures respectively for insert, update and delete. That is giving me error. Can anyone help me sorting out this..

[image: This is the error]

```
create or replace 
    PACKAGE body USERS_tapi
    IS
      -- insert
    PROCEDURE ins(
        p_FIRSTNAME IN USERS.FIRSTNAME%type ,
        p_ADDRESS   IN USERS.ADDRESS%type ,
        p_ROLEID    IN USERS.ROLEID%type DEFAULT NULL ,
        p_USERNAME  IN USERS.USERNAME%type ,
        p_PASSWORD  IN USERS.PASSWORD%type ,
        p_USERID    IN USERS.USERID%type ,
        p_LASTNAME  IN USERS.LASTNAME%type,
        O_val OUT NUMBER
        )
    IS
    BEGIN
    select count(*) as cnt  from USERS where username=p_USERNAME and password=p_PASSWORD;
        if cnt = 0 then
           INSERT INTO USERS(
            FIRSTNAME ,
            ADDRESS ,
            ROLEID ,
            USERNAME ,
            PASSWORD ,
            USERID ,
            LASTNAME
          )
          VALUES
          (
            p_FIRSTNAME ,
            p_ADDRESS ,
            p_ROLEID ,
            p_USERNAME ,
            p_PASSWORD ,
            USERS_SEQ.nextval ,
            p_LASTNAME
          );


        O_val:=0;
         else if cnt > 0 then
        O_val:=1;
        else 
        O_val:=2;
        END IF;
        return O_val;
    END;
    -- update

PROCEDURE upd
  (
    p_FIRSTNAME IN USERS.FIRSTNAME%type ,
    p_ADDRESS   IN USERS.ADDRESS%type ,
    p_ROLEID    IN USERS.ROLEID%type DEFAULT NULL ,
    p_USERNAME  IN USERS.USERNAME%type ,
    p_PASSWORD  IN USERS.PASSWORD%type ,
    p_USERID    IN USERS.USERID%type ,
    p_LASTNAME  IN USERS.LASTNAME%type
  )
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE USERS
  SET FIRSTNAME = p_FIRSTNAME ,
    ADDRESS     = p_ADDRESS ,
    ROLEID      = p_ROLEID ,
    USERNAME    = p_USERNAME ,
    PASSWORD    = p_PASSWORD ,
    LASTNAME    = p_LASTNAME
  WHERE USERID  = p_USERID;
END;
-- del
PROCEDURE del(
    p_USERID IN USERS.USERID%type )
IS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM USERS WHERE USERID = p_USERID;
END;
END USERS_tapi;
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the Package Specification in addition to the package body. Are you variables (cnt, O_val) declared in there?

Comment: Also to store the result of a select statement into a previously declared variable, you need to use `INTO`. `select count(*) INTO cnt  from USERS where username=p_USERNAME and password=p_PASSWORD;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `elsif` instead of `else if` in the following line :

```
else if cnt > 0 then
```

The former is just one more case in your condition block.
The latter syntax is starting a nested condition block in the else part of the first condition block. That nested block would need its own END IF to work.

You could also use a CASE statement :

```
CASE
    WHEN cnt = 0 then
        -- insert statement
        O_val:=0;
    WHEN cnt > 0 then
        O_val:=1;
    else 
        O_val:=2;
END CASE;
```